# Modify the value of a std::unordered_map element in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, stl, unordered-map

I have the following problem. I have a `std::unordered_map` that contains an object as the value. Now I want to modify an object that I previously inserted.

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    float x;
    float y;
};
```

```
std::unordered_map<int, Point> points;
// ... add some values to it ...
points[1].x = 20.f; // error?
```

I get a weird long compile error about point not being able to be default constructed. The way I understand it `operator []` returns a reference to the mapped type (aka the value), so why can't I modify it?

Comment: I think you need a default constructor for `Point` class so add `Point() : x(0), y(0) {}` so a ctor that takes no params

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the key isn't in the map, `operator []` is **required** to create one. The expression

```
points[1]
```

needs to be able to default-insert a `Point` in case of lookup failure (regardless of whether lookup failure ever occurs - this is a compile-time requirement not a run-time check). That requirement cannot be satisfied by `Point` because `Point` is not default constructible. Hence the compile error. If you want to use `unordered_map::operator[]` , you'll need to add a default constructor.

If a default constructed `Point` doesn't make sense for your usage - then you simply cannot use `operator[]` and will have to use `find` throughout (or `at()` if you're okay with exceptions):

```
auto it = points.find(1);
if (it != points.end()) {
   it->second.x = 20.f;
}

points.at(1).x = 20.f; // can throw
```

Comment: Or you could just use `emplace` to avoid the `std::make_pair`. You'd also need to use `points.at(1)` instead of `points[1]` for access.

Comment: The actual failure to find the point isn't what causes the error.  The possibility it could fail causes the compiler to write the code where it *does* fail, which causes the compile-time error.  This means that the next lime, `points[1].x` *also* will cause the error, despite any `points.insert` stuff you do first.  In short, `[]` *will not work* with a type that cannot be default-constructed.

Comment: @Yakk Didn't think I was implying that it did. Better wording?

Comment: @Barry sure, but this means you didn't solve the OP's problem.  The very next line uses `[]` again to modify the element.  I'm guessing the OP tried to write a MCVE and didn't notice that an earlier part of the MCVE was generating the same error, not the line in question.  In the text, the OP is clearly concerned about the `points[1].x` line.

Comment: @Yakk Fair point. Focused the answer and dropped the bit about insertion entirely.

Comment: Yes I rephrased my answer. It was confusing, because of the wrong code. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

[`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) constructs an object of mapped type in-place if no element exists with the given key. In a map with a [default allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), `operator[]` requires the mapped type to be [default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible). More generally, the mapped type must be [emplace constuctible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EmplaceConstructible).

The easy solution is to add a default constructor to your class.

```
Point() : Point(0.f, 0.f) {}
```

If this isn't possible, you will have to use other functions to access map elements.

To access an existing mapped object, you can using [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at), which will throw a [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception if no element exists with the given key.

```
points.at(1).x = 20.f;
```

Alternatively, you can use [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find), which returns an iterator to the element with the given key, or to the element following the last element in the map (see [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/end2)) if no such element exists.

```
auto it = points.find(1);
if (it != points.end())
{
    it->second = 20.f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` cannot be used on a `map` or `unordered_map` without the data being default-constructible.  This is because if the object is not found, it will create it via default-construction.

The easy solution is to make your type default-constructible.

if not:

```
template<class M, class K, class F>
bool access_element( M& m, K const& k, F&& f ) {
  auto it = m.find(k);
  if (it == m.end())
    return false;
  std::forward<F>(f)(it->second);
  return true;
}
```

then:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Point> points;
points.emplace(1, Point(10.f, 10.f));
access_element(points, 1, [](Point& elem){
  elem.x = 20.f;
});
```

will do what `points[1].x = 20.f;` does without risking exception code or having to make `Point` default-constructible.

This pattern -- where we pass a function to mutate/access an element to a container -- is stealing a page from Haskell monad design.  I would make it return `optional<X>` instead of `bool`, where `X` is the return type of the passed in function, but that is going a bit far.